# Problem with electric start

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, yamaha

I've got a TTR125LE that runs great but the electric start will only engage in neutral. I need some help and I don't want to do something about it unless I fully understand the situation because I might make it worse

Comment: Welcome to the site @D.smitty, this doesn't sound like an actual problem to me, probably designed that way as SolarMike says. Is there some sort of problem you're trying to resolve? Is it that you find it inconvenient to switch to neutral to start if you've stalled?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in neutral is the correct, safe operation.

If you can start it when it is in any gear then that is not safe and needs correcting.

Imagine if you start it in a gear and it runs away from you...

Comment: Too right @SolarMike, I've done that very same bonehead maneuver once, fortunately it only resulted in pride damage.

Comment: @GdD Glad to hear it was only that...